# How can I add automatic decreasing time zone in my react.js program?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Header (){
const locale = 'en';
const [today] = useState(new Date());
const time = today.toLocaleTimeString(locale, { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true, minute: 'numeric', second:'numeric' });


return <div className="header"> <p className="header"> Current Time {time} </p> </div>
}

export default Header;
```

This is the header component of my project. I want to display an automatic decreasing countdown timer in the format of, " Hour: Minute: Second ".  [UI of react.js project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwaTF.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CountDown Timer with start/Pause and reset button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54733321/countdown-timer-with-start-pause-and-reset-button)

Comment: Actually, I need an automatic timezone code without buttons.

Comment: That post has methods for a decreasing timer using `setInterval`. I think you can learn from it - disregard the buttons and button functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date) {
  var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);

  var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
  var hours = date.getHours();

  newDate.setHours(hours - offset);

  return newDate;
}
```

The offset inside the function will automatically check the time difference and adjust it to local time.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking for - although the question mentions "timezone" in the title, a timezone has nothing to do with it. He wants a timer that counts down, in `HH:MM:SS` format. At least that is what it looks like from the rest of the OP